# How make my page wait till the hook got all data?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I'm building a react app based on TypeScript template and one of my pages is loading before the hook completes the load.

I tried makings async await but it is a hook, didn't work well.

How can I build something to wait my hook completes and then load it on the page?

My page:

```js
export function Home(){


    const { topEventsSelected } = useGetTopEvents(3);

    

    return(
        <div className="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
            <NavBar/>
                
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row mt-4 mb-4 gap">
                        <div className="col-md">
                            <div className="card">
                                <div className="sizingt d-flex card-body flex-column align-items-center sizingt">
                                    <h1>TOP Eventos</h1>
                                    {topEventsSelected.map((eventoInfo)=>
                                        moment(eventoInfo.dataFinal).isBefore() || eventoInfo.cancelado === 'Y' ? 
                                            (
                                                console.log()
                                            ):(
                                                <BlueCard props={eventoInfo}/>
                                            )
                                        
                                    )}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Here is my hook (note that the file is .ts):

```js
export function useGetTopEvents(quant: number){
    const [eventValues, setEventValues] = useState<Evento[]>([]);
    const [topEvents, setTopEvents] = useState<Evento[]>([]);
    const [topEventsSelected, setTopEventsSelected] = useState<Evento[]>([]);
    
    function organizeEvents(){
        //organazing events by confirmed users
        let topAllEvents = []
        for(let organizer of eventValues){
            if(organizer.confirmNumb > 0){
                topAllEvents.push(organizer)
            }
        }
        topAllEvents.sort((a,b) => b.confirmNumb - a.confirmNumb)
        setTopEvents(topAllEvents)

        //organazing events by quantity selected
        let topSelected = topAllEvents;
        topSelected.sort((a,b) => b.confirmNumb - a.confirmNumb).slice(0,3);
        setTopEventsSelected(topSelected);
    }

    useEffect(() =>{
        const eventRef = database.ref(`eventos`);

        eventRef.once('value', evento => {
            //console.log(evento.val())
            const databaseEventos = evento.val();

            const firebaseEvent: FirebaseEventos = databaseEventos ?? {};
            
            const parsedEventos = Object.entries(firebaseEvent).map(([key, value])=>{
                return{
                    id: key,
                    autorID: value.authorID,
                    autorNome: value.authorName,
                    categoria: value.category,
                    dataInicio: value.startDate,
                    dataFinal: value.endDate,
                    titulo: value.title,
                    cancelado: value.canceled,
                    confirmNumb: Object.entries(value.confirmados ?? {}).length
                }
            }) 
            
            //console.log(parsedEventos)
            
            setEventValues(parsedEventos);

            organizeEvents();
        })

    }, [quant])

    return{topEvents, topEventsSelected}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

troubleshooting it I realized that the code was taking longer to assign the data to the parameter on method `setEventValues(parsedEventos);`, so then, as it is a multi-thread, it started running `organizeEvents()` before complete to assign data to setEventValues.

To fix that by sending the data by the function parameter: `organizeEvents(parsedEventos)` and then processing the info and saving it in the consts.

I also changed the organizeEvents to be async, so avoiding corruption

Here is the final code for the hook:

```js
export function useGetTopEvents(quant: number){
    
    const [topEvents, setTopEvents] = useState<Evento[]>([]);
    const [topEventsSelected, setTopEventsSelected] = useState<Evento[]>([]);

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
    
    async function organizeEvents(eventValues: Evento[]){
        //organazing events by confirmed users

        let topAllEvents:Evento[] = <Evento[]>[];

        await eventValues.forEach(element =>{
            if(element.confirmNumb > 0){
                topAllEvents.push(element)
            }
        })

        await topAllEvents.sort((a,b) => b.confirmNumb - a.confirmNumb)
        await setTopEvents(topAllEvents)

        //organazing events by quantity selected
        let topSelected = topAllEvents;
        await topSelected.sort((a,b) => b.confirmNumb - a.confirmNumb).slice(0,3);
        await setTopEventsSelected(topSelected);
        
        await setLoading(false)
        
    }

    useEffect(() =>{
        const eventRef = database.ref(`eventos`);

        eventRef.once('value', evento => {
            //console.log(evento.val())
            const databaseEventos = evento.val();

            const firebaseEvent: FirebaseEventos = databaseEventos ?? {};
            
            const parsedEventos = Object.entries(firebaseEvent).map(([key, value])=>{
                return{
                    id: key,
                    autorID: value.authorID,
                    autorNome: value.authorName,
                    categoria: value.category,
                    dataInicio: value.startDate,
                    dataFinal: value.endDate,
                    titulo: value.title,
                    cancelado: value.canceled,
                    confirmNumb: Object.entries(value.confirmados ?? {}).length
                }
            }) 
            
            //console.log(parsedEventos)
            
            organizeEvents(parsedEventos);
            
        })

    }, [quant])

    return{topEvents, topEventsSelected, loading}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution would be to add a conditional render on your render component. In you custom hook you could add one more state for loading, and then you can render your component based on that.

```
export function useGetTopEvents(quant: number) {

  const [loading,set] = useState<Boolean>(true)

  function organizeEvents() {
    //organazing events by confirmed users
    ...your function
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      ...
      //console.log(parsedEventos)

      setEventValues(parsedEventos);
      setLoading(false) // set the state to false
      organizeEvents();
    });
  }, [quant]);

  return {topEvents, topEventsSelected, loading};

  // also return the loading state so you could use it with your custom hook
}
```

Then you could use the loading as follow

```
const { topEventsSelected ,loading} = useGetTopEvents(3);


      return(
        <div className="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
            <NavBar/>
                
               {loading ? ...loading : your render login}
)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I tried that and Looading shows up and when it desapear, the return still empty. I did some Console.log and I see information in the hook useState

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do will be conditional rendering of the elements in your return.

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
```

Inside your return method

```
   return ({
data : <>Your component</> ? <LoadingState />
})
```